# How to fix syntax highlight not working on Xcode 13.1?

Tags: swift, xcode, syntax-highlighting, xcode13

Recently I upgraded from 12 to 13.1 and moved my code base accordingly. Sadly since I upgraded i cannot have syntax highlight to work. Code completion and symbols are working correctly.

My project uses Carthage and SPM.

I already tried every solution posted here on SO:

- reinstalled xcode from scratch 2 - 3 times
- removed derived data, build folders and so
- clean up all my carthages and rebuild them from scratch
- already checked I don't have any missing compiling sources

I have a macbook pro m1 with 1tb ssd 16gb ram

Comment: There are known issues with Xcode 13.1. Downgrade to 13.0 or something for now.